# appendChild not appending textNode parent

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Case I: *Working*

```
var k = document.createElement("div"),
t1 = document.getElementById("test1");
k.appendChild(document.createTextNode("inner1"))
t1.appendChild(k);
```

Output:

```
<div id="test1">
    <div>inner1</div>
</div>
```

Case II: *Not working*

```
var k = document.createElement("div"),
t1 = document.getElementById("test1");
t1.appendChild(k.appendChild(document.createTextNode("inner1")));
```

Output:

```
<div id="test1">inner1</div>
```

Why in case 2 their is no surrounding div?

Comment: See if this helps -- "The appendChild method returns a reference to added node" -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Comment: you want `k.appendChild(document.createTextNode("inner1")).parentNode`, [parentNode docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second snippet you would want to use the [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) property

```
var k = document.createElement("div"),
t1 = document.getElementById("test1");
t1.appendChild(
  k.appendChild(
     document.createTextNode("inner1")
  ) //will return the textnode and not the div, 
    //so we need to get parentNode which will be the div
  .parentNode
);
```

your second snippet evaluates to basically doing this

```
var textNode = k.appendChild(document.createTextNode("inner1"));
t1.appendChild(textNode);
```

using the parentNode evaluates to doing this

```
var textNode = k.appendChild(document.createTextNode("inner1"));
var k2 = textNode.parentNode;
//k === k2
t1.appendChild(k2);
```

Comment: I was just saying we should delete the comments because they dont really have anything to do with the actual question and answer. As for the ajax just google ajax tutorials, lots of them out there. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/ here is one on the newer xhr2

Comment: no i dont use linkedin, just get enough rep and you will be able to use the chat part of stackoverflow.